# jquery script works in all browsers offline and online except online on chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a weird problem:

check out this page i just uploaded: 
http://www.gloskincare.be/instituten.html

there is a dropdown option menu with all kind of options: (check in firefox or safari)

when people select a certain option, all other instances hide.

**HTML**
here's option html:

```
<select id="stadlijst">
    <option value="javascript:history.go(0)">Selecteer een provincie</option>
    <option value="javascript:history.go(0)">Toon alle provincies</option>
    <option value="antwerpen">Antwerpen</option>
    <option value="limburg">Limburg</option>
    <option value="oost-vlaanderen">Oost-Vlaanderen</option>
    <option value="west-vlaanderen">West-Vlaanderen</option>
    <option value="vlaams-brabant">Vlaams-Brabant</option>
    <option value="henegouwen">Henegouwen</option>
    <option value="luik">Luik</option>
    <option value="luxemburg">Luxemburg</option>
    <option value="namen">Namen</option>
    <option value="waals-brabant">Waals-Brabant</option>
</select>
```

here's the other part

```
<div class="lijst userstyle1 row">
    <div class="stad-antwerpen adcont col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <h3>Loox4Life</h3>    
         <h5>
                    Verlatstraat 3<br>
                    2000 Antwerpen<br><br>
                    +32 495 78 11 50<br>
                    <a href="http://www.loox4life.com">www.loox4life.com</a></h5>

    </div>
    <div class="stad-vlaams-brabant adcont col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <h3>Kim Skincare</h3>

            <h5>Kleine Mechelsebaan 16<br>
                    3200 Aarschot<br><br>
                    +32 498 21 80 40<br>
                    <a href="http://www.kimvangramberen.be">www.kimvangramberen.be</a></h5>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#stadlijst').on('change', function () {
        $('.lijst div').show().not(".stad-" + this.value).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: working for me fine, mention your chrome version and OS

Comment: chrome version: Version 44.0.2403.155 (64-bit)

OS: mac osx Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: Works for me too (in 44.0.2403.155 m, Win 7 64bit) – but your first two options throw an error when selected: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .stad-javascript:history.go(0)`

Comment: I'm on the same version. Console reports: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .stad-javascript:history.go(0)`. Try: `"window.history.go(-1); return false;"` but not sure if this will work. Basically `javascript:history.go(0)` won't work in Chrome afaik

Comment: yea i used javascript:history.go(0) as an option because there needed to be an option to reset everything.

do you happen to know a solution? so i can implement an option to reset it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what it is. Are you using AdBlock in Chrome? AdBlock is hiding divs with the class of `adcont`. Disable AdBlock and try again.

Comment: OMG! you are a hero sir! :p